# ¿Por qué innerHTML solo funciona al finalizar mi bucle?

Tags: javascript, html

Mirad, tengo este bucle for:

```
for(var i=0;i<=3;i++) {
    mida=parseInt(prompt("Escribe la mida"));
    altura=parseInt(prompt("Escriba la altura"));

    div.innerHTML=div.innerHTML+"Base: "+mida+"<br>Altura: "+altura+" 
    <br>Superficie: "+mida*(altura/1.5);
}
```

"Div" es un div que tengo en HTML, el problema es que el div solo se muestra en mi pagina cuando acaba el bucle no cuando acaba una pasada, alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: ¿Quieres que se escriban 3 parejas de divs con la información escrita en el alert?

Comment: He cambiado el codigo que es mas claro ahora, sí, yo quiero 3 divs, que se ejecuten nada mas dar una vuelta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando haces esto:

```
div.innerHTML=....................
```

El valor asignado al elemento div se sobreescribirá por el generado en la siguiente vuelta, lo cual *elimina* lo que previamente se habia almacenado.

En estos casos lo mas simple es modificar esa sintaxis a esto:

```
div.innerHTML+=...................
```

Por cierto al final del contenido dinámico que le inyectas a tu div dale un saltó de línea por que sino genera un resultado algo difícil de leer

Quedando tu código de esta forma:

```html
    <div>
      
    </div>
    <script>
      let div = document.querySelector('div');
      
      for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
      mida=parseInt(prompt("Escribe la mida"));
      altura=parseInt(prompt("Escriba la altura"));
      div.innerHTML+="Base: "+mida+"<br>Altura: "+altura+"<br>Superficie: "+mida*(altura/1.5)+"<br />";
    }
    </script>
```

Ya como algo extra pero no menos importante:

- Considera usar [`let` en sustitución de `var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let)
- Para constituir el texto que le das a cada div, mejor usa [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Comment: El código es `div.innerHTML=div.innerHTML+"Base: "+mida+"<br>Altura: "+altura+"  <br>Superficie: "+mida*(altura/1.5);`, no sobreescribe el el HTML

Comment: @SJuan76 muy buena observación, no lo tenía presente de dicha forma, igual considero que le ayudaría mucho al OP si le publicas eso como solución.